# find if date is older than 30 days

Tags: php, string, datetime, date, time

The date string looks like this

`2011-08-19 17:14:40`

(year-month-day  hours:minutes:seconds)

How can I find out if the date is older than the current date with more than 30 days?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
 if(strtotime('2011-08-19 17:14:40') < strtotime('-30 days')) {
     // this is true
 }
```

Besides, this string looks like it is stored in SQL as datetime/timestamp field. You can directly select all entries from your database with old dates using:

```
SELECT ... WHERE `datetime` + INTERVAL 30 DAY < NOW()
```

Comment: Note that months may have 4 combination of days: 28, 29 30 and 31.

Comment: Note that neither question nor answer use word month (except in description pf format)

Answer (score 59):

If you are on PHP 5.3 or higher you can do:

```
$someDate = new \DateTime('2011-08-19 17:14:40');
$now = new \DateTime();

if($someDate->diff($now)->days > 30) {
   echo 'The date was more than 30 days ago.';
}
```

Comment: can you link to the documentation for diff($now)->days? i would like to tweak it for hours not days. thanks.

Comment: [diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) returns a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). DateInterval has an `h` property for 'hours' but it is actually a fragment of the difference (as it relates to y (years), m (months), d (days), etc). To get hours, I'd do `($now->getTimestamp() - $someDate->getTimestamp()) / 3600`. This would return a decimal. You could then optionally use [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), etc. if you want it as an integer.

Comment: I like this answer much better than the accepted one. The `diff` method looks very elegant.

Comment: One liner:  `(new DateTime('2021-08-10'))->diff(new DateTime())->days > 30`

Comment: Even better with `$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();`

Answer (score 8):

You can use Carbon as follows

```
if (30 - ((new \Carbon\Carbon($given_date, 'UTC'))->diffInDays()) < 0) {
    echo "The date is older than 30 days";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('2011-08-19 17:14:40') + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 < time();
```

Comment: It should be `strtotime('2011-08-19 17:14:40') + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 < time();` correct it.

Comment: @nobody You have >2000 rep. You could correct it yourself, like I did. :)

Comment: @gion_13 It's generally a bad idea to do those sorts of `24 * 60 * 60` calculations, because they can become inaccurate when dealing with things like daylight savings time. It's better to use something like RiaD suggests, and let `strtotime()` handle the relative time calculations.

Comment: strtotime('2011-08-19 17:14:40')+(30 * 86400) < time();

Comment: @Agent I disagree with your point above, `30 * 24 * 60 * 60` is always exactly `30 days` no matter where in the universe you are.

Comment: @tada That doesn't change anything. It's still just as susceptible (in the *exact* same way, since you're substituting a calculation for its exact result) to DST and related issues.

Comment: @nobody That depends entirely on how we're defining "days". If we're talking about "30 standard days worth of seconds", then you're right. If we're talking about "this time 30 days ago" then you're wrong. If you cross a DST boundary within that range, the you'll get a time that's off by an hour 30 days ago. It's a subtle point, but it's one worth taking into consideration.

Comment: @Agent I see what you mean, +1 vote for DST as the worst invention of human being from the point of view of a programmer.

Comment: @nobody Time in general. Jon Skeet was on the SO podcast back in the day, working on something that I think turned out to be Android, and talking about all the weird things that can happen with DST and Time Zones. It was pretty interesting.