# timestamp query not retrieving results?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there :) I am doing a query, and it will pull results where the timestamp is more than 30 days old. Here's what I've put so far:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT time FROM table1 WHERE open_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS)");
```

So as you can see, it will try to find results more than 30 days old, however when I execute the query, it doesn't select any rows, even though the column field "open_time" is more than 30 days old.

Any suggestions I do greatly appreciate :)

Comment: Well what is the type of the 'open_time' field? Is it a date/datetime/...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to cast the date field?

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT time FROM table1 WHERE CAST(open_time AS DATE) < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS)");
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe you should use this tricky query:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT time FROM table1 WHERE open_time <
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))"):
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried to cast it and it didn't seem to work :(

Comment: What is the type of your field `open_time`?

Comment: It is a timestamp field, it shows the date (yyyy-mm-dd) and the time (HH-MM-SS)

Comment: @JoshuaGreenhough I edited my post. Can you please show us sample data?

Comment: Hi, sorry im just a bit busy at the moment, ill be able to try things out in a few hours, sorry man.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT time FROM table1 WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30
     DAY")
```

or

try this one also for your reference

[timestampadd()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` > timestampadd(day, -30, now());
```

[try this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130738/find-if-date-is-older-than-30-days)