# Get all records older than 24 hours in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to get all data from sql table which are older than 24 hours for that i 
have written following query but it is not working properly.

```
$this->db->where('DATE(`created_at`) <','strtotime(-1 days)')->get('table_name')->result();
```

> created_at is of date time data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `INTERVAL`

```
$this->db->where("DATE(`created_at`) + INTERVAL 1 DAY < NOW() ")->get('table_name')->result();
```

---

Read More

1. [find if date is older than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130738/find-if-date-is-older-than-30-days)