# Check if data updated_at 24 hours ago OR a day ago (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-9

I am able to get days ago for each row in dattable using carbon. (view CustomController.php)

But before the user is able to edit the data. I want to check if the data is updated a day ago or 24 hours ago.
if 24 hours or a day passed user can't update the data if it is within 24 hours range then the user can update the data

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('table_sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('session')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**CustomController.php**

```
public function EditSession(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $session = SessionModel::find($id);
    return response()->json($session);
}

public function FetchSession()
{
    $session = SessionModel::all();
    $output = '';
    if ($session->count() > 0) {
        $output .= '<table class="table text-center align-middle table-flush table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>              
          <th width="50px"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="main_checkbox" id="master"></th>
          <th width="10%">ID</th>
          <th>Session</th>
          <th width="50%">Action</th>
          <th>Updated On</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($session as $session) {
            $output .= '<tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="sub_master" name="session_checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="' . $session->id . '"></td>
            <td>' . $session->id . '</td>                
            <td>' . $session->session . '</td>
            <td>
              <a href="#" id="' . $session->id . '" class="text-success mx-1 editIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSessionModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>
              <!-- Edit Button -->

              <a href="#" id="' . $session->id . '" class="text-danger mx-1 deleteIcon"><i class="bi-trash h4"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td scope="row"> 
              <label id="timeLabel">' . $session->updated_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) . ' days ago</label>
            <!-- **getting days ago using this code** -->

            </td>                
          </tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody></table>';
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo '<h1 class="text-center text-shifondary my-5">No record present in the database!</h1>';
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('fetch-sessions', [CustomController::class, 'FetchSession'])->name('session.fetch.route');
Route::get('edit-session', [CustomController::class, 'EditSession'])->name('session.edit.route');
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<div class="table-responsive p-3" id="show_all_sessions">

</div>

{{-- edit Modal --}}
<div class="modal-body">
            <form action="#" autocomplete="off" method="POST" id="edit_session_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="session_id" id="session_id">
                <input type="" name="session_time" id="session_time">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="session">Session <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input  id="session_i" name="session_i" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Session Name">                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger mb-1" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="edit_session_btn" class="btn btn-secondary mb-1">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

{{-- //Scripts --}}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function fetchAllSessions() {      
  var _url = '{{ route("session.fetch.rn") }}';      
  $.ajax({
    url: _url,
    method: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
      $("#show_all_sessions").html(response);
      $("table").DataTable();
     }
   });
 }

// edit session ajax request for edit button on datatable
$(document).on('click', '.editIcon', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = $(this).attr('id');
  //let time = $("#timeLabel").attr('text');
  var _url = '{{ route("session.edit.route") }}';
  $.ajax({
    url: _url,
    method: 'get',
    data: {
      id: id,
      _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    success: function(response) {                
      // here some logic tocheck if clicked data updated 24 hours ago or a day ago using if else.
              
      $("#session_id").val(response.id);
      $("#session_i").val(response.session);          
     }
   });
 });

});
</script>
```

**DataTable looks like this**

[image: Dattable]

Comment: you can store value of "$session->updated_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now())" in any variable and then use that variable to able and disable submit button

Comment: @AqibJaved yes I am storing it in table within this label , can you post some logic to disable edit button'<label id="timeLabel">' . $session->updated_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) . ' days ago</label>'

Comment: @JohnLobo yes I am using same to show the data in table , as you can see in screenshot, but I want some logic to disable edit button to according to time

Comment: <a href="#" id="' . $session->id . '" class="text-success mx-1 editIcon @if( $session->created_at->diffInDays(now())>24)disable-link @endif " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSessionModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>


and add css 
disable-link {pointer-events: none;}

Comment: @JohnLobo  Thanks for the help, it is working good but it is disabling link straight and ignoring if statement
   class="text-success mx-1 editIcon @ if( $session->updated_at->diffInHours(now()) > 24) disable-link @ endif " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSessionModal">

Comment: @ShubhamSahu i can see space between @ and if and try to remove it .if its still not working then try to print   $session->updated_at->diffInHours(now()) so you can see how many records have greater than 24 hours

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes i have added space in this comment only. SO not allowing add multiple @ ... checking

Comment: @ShubhamSahu okay.. just print values as i mentioned so you can check which record has less than 24 hours .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243472/discussion-between-shubham-sahu-and-john-lobo).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find if date is older than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130738/find-if-date-is-older-than-30-days)

Comment: @jspit tried but the if statement not working for   table inside  controller

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debugging service for your code.
Please give a minimally reproducible example with the data for the input and the desired result.
Please also show what you have tried with your input data and the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are rendering table in controller,so you can use ternary operator to  dynamically load class name based on condition

```
 <a href="#" id="' . $session->id . '" class="text-success mx-1 editIcon '.( $session->created_at->diffInHours(now())>24?"disable-link":null).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSessionModal">
```

i suggest you to move html content from controller to blade so you can easily use blade syntax

```
<a href="#" id="{{ $session->id}}" class="text-success mx-1 editIcon @if( $session->created_at->diffInDays(now())>24)disable-link @endif " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSessionModal"><i class="bi-pencil-square h4"></i></a>
```